# Is there anyway to transfer emails from a linux server into a windows server?

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, mail-server, windows-hosting

I work with a company where the previous website was designed in php and it was hosted in a linux server, now we have re-developed our website using .net framework for which we are planning to purchase a windows hosting.

Everything else seems alright except the email part, the company wants a backup of the emails in the new web server (windows server) too.

So is there any solution for it ?

Comment: An important question is where were you hosting your email earlier. This is of-course possible .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for programming-related questions, so this is off topic. Ref [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), in particular the section "If your question is not specifically on-topic for Stack Overflow", where you will find a list of other Stack Exchange sites that may be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the emails stored? It should not make any difference what OS you use. Find the place where they are stored and try to port them to the new system.

Try searching the code for the email configuration and chances are high that you find the place.

Possible places where I would search first:

- Source Code -> configuration / email sending
- Database on the webserver
- In the mailbox which is maybe used